# Call PHP function from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX, and can't get a php function to run.

The AJAX post request is working as it should, here's the code:

```
function thumbs(i) {
    $('.thumbs-up' + String(i)).click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('up');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"item.php",
            data:'act=up&function' + String(i) + '=true&user=' + email,
            success: function(){
            }
        });
    });

for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    thumbs(i);
}
```

The above works, I receive all the correct values.

Then the PHP code that should run is here:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {

    if ($_POST['function' . $i] == 'true') {
        //code that should run but does not
    }
}
```

The count variable is the same. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't include the full url in my ajax post request. It was a dynamic url, so i just had to add the GET variable to the end of the url string. I apologize for not including this, there's no way anyone would have known.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `get` parameters instead of sending `post` parameters. See the example in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: The `data` method is way better than trying to smack together something using `String`, though it would be nice if your example here was based on the original question.

Comment: I think it's easily replicated, don't you?

Comment: Exactly why I'm saying a better answer would have done that. Examples are great, but demonstrations are even better.

Comment: This turns out to be not true. jQuery does `POST` the `data` as part of the request body and *not* over the Querystring.